# Error using imdilate Expected input number 1, IM, to be one of these types

Tags: matlab

```
`SE=sterel('square',3);
 mask = load('masque.mat');
 dilated_mask = imdilate(mask,ES);`
```

I have already mask of an image (it's a matrix with -1 (region)  and 0 (background)) its name is "masque.mat".

After executing this code a variable "mask" 1*1 struct is created, when i click on it "segimg_t" 360*480 double appeared. when I click on the "segimg_t" the matrix of the mask appears.

The problem that imdilate() don't accept a truct type, how should i process to solve this problem?
And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. You need to pass the image, not the struct that contains the image;
2. The structuring element is misspelled.

Thus:

```
dilated_mask = imdilate(mask.segimg_t,SE);
```

Comment: @Devel Then you should chose it as an answer. :-)

Comment: I have one more question please, if I want to get the "masque.mat" in a matrix not in a struct is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not directly, unfortunately. the `load` function returns only structures. However, if you work in a script, and *don't* use a variable to get the result -- i.e. instead of `mask = load('masque.mat');` you use only `load('masque.mat');` -- the the `load` function will create directly the variable `segimg_t` in your global workspace, so you can then call `dilated_mask = imdilate(segimg_t,SE);`